# How to remove these swagger warnings, about HEAD and OPTIONS?

Tags: express, request, cors, swagger, httpresponse

I used swagger on express js and when I do a query I am getting this warnings.

`WARNING! Unable to find a Swagger operation that matches HEAD ...` - this will show if I will try to use curl.

`WARNING! Unable to find a Swagger operation that matches OPTIONS ...` - while this one is when accessed from a webpage.

I already add `helmet` and this to the code.

```
app.use((_, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Content-Type, api_key, Authorization',
  );
  next();
});
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, I mean the warning is not showing anymore. The solution is just a one liner, sending HTTP status of `200` telling the browser that the request is supported.

````
export function optionCORS(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {

  // I am just setting the headers if the request is an OPTION or HEAD
  // For now I didn't interfere with the other request like POST, etc.
  // I have a guess that swagger is is doing it.
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
    const origin: string = req.headers.origin as string;

    // On my angular I have interceptor that will set the ```withCredentials```
    // option to true, so I cant use * on Allow-Origin so I grab the
    // request.headers.origin an used it.
    // Also we need to set the Allow-Credentials to true.
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    // Then the usual headers.
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');    
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Content-Length, Origin, ' +
      'X-Requested-With',
    );

    // And this what I miss, just the HTTP 200 status.
    // So the client will know that the request is supported.
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return;
  }

  // If the request is not an OPTIONS or HEAD continue as usual,
  // it look like swagger is handling it.
  next();
}
````

Then you can use it as middleware.

```
app.use(optionCORS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using `swagger-express-middleware` set `WARN=off` environment variable

https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-express-middleware/blob/ed73f82e57adb868b10e1989dac555b8d943dab8/lib/helpers/util.js#L27